# Cancel mutation react-apollo with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, graphql, apollo-client

Hello i'm looking to cancel a mutation on User Click .
i'm using buildAxiosFetch with apollo to get onUploadProgres .

```
 const httpLink = new createUploadLink({
  uri: 'https://api.digividz.tech/graphql',
fetch: buildAxiosFetch(axios, (config, input, init) => ({
  ...config,
  onUploadProgress: init.onUploadProgress,
   
  
 })),
```

});
is there any way to get cancel method of axios ?
thanks

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/40 - some ideas ... save cancel tokens, use them in some local resolver?

Comment: it may helps someone https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client/issues/88